# How do I make the active button in my tab have the "active" class?

Tags: javascript, css, html, tabs

I need your help, please.

I have to add the "active" class in the buttons depending on the tab that is active (I'm new with javascript) I'm using pure javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="buttonTab" id="tab1" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(1);">Tab 1</button>
<button class="buttonTab" id="tab2" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(2);">Tab 2</button>

<br />

<div class="contentTab" id="tab1Content" style="display: block;">
     This is the content.
</div>
<div class="contentTab" id="tab2Content" style="display: none;">
     This is the content2.
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.buttonTab {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #333333;
}
.buttonTab.active {
   color: #333333;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
//Hide All Tabs
document.getElementById('tab1Content').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('tab2Content').style.display="none";

//Show the Selected Tab
document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex + 'Content').style.display="block";  
}
```

I hope you can help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add/remove classes to element's classList.

```js
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
//Hide All Tabs
document.getElementById('tab1Content').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('tab2Content').style.display="none";

//Show the Selected Tab
document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex + 'Content').style.display="block";  
if(tabIndex==1){
document.getElementById('tab' + 2 ).classList.remove("active");
}
else if(tabIndex==2){
document.getElementById('tab' + 1 ).classList.remove("active");
}
document.getElementById('tab' + tabIndex ).classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.buttonTab {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #333333;
}
.buttonTab.active {
   color: #333333;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonTab" id="tab1" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(1);">Tab 1</button>
<button class="buttonTab" id="tab2" onClick="JavaScript:selectTab(2);">Tab 2</button>

<br />

<div class="contentTab" id="tab1Content" style="display: block;">
     This is the content.
</div>
<div class="contentTab" id="tab2Content" style="display: none;">
     This is the content2.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something very simple that parallels your existing code  nicely consider this.

Note that this is not the most efficient code, it is simply most like your existing code. Capturing all tabs in one nodelist and looping over them as in other posts is surely more practical way to go.

```
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
  //Hide All Tabs
  document.getElementById("tab1Content").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("tab2Content").style.display = "none";

  // Remove active class  all tabs
  document.getElementById("tab1").classList.remove("active");
  document.getElementById("tab2").classList.remove("active");

  //Show the Selected Tab
  document.getElementById("tab" + tabIndex + "Content").style.display = "block";
  //Activate clicked tab
  document.getElementById("tab" + tabIndex).classList.add("active");
}
```